# jQuery não quer executar no mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou usando uma função para que quando a pessoa clicar no inputs o valor ser substituído por valor monetário, porém no celular só funciona se a pessoa clicar em "ok" ou "ir", e eu queria que ele executasse assim que a pessoa clicar no input.

Código usado:

```
$("#valorsaquemobi").click(function(){
var mask = {
  money: function() {
    var el = this
    ,exec = function(v) {
    v = v.replace(/\D/g,"");
    v = new String(Number(v));
    var len = v.length;
    if (1== len)
    v = v.replace(/(\d)/,"0.0$1");
    else if (2 == len)
    v = v.replace(/(\d)/,"0.$1");
    else if (len > 2) {
    v = v.replace(/(\d{2})$/,'.$1');
    }
    return v;
    };

    setTimeout(function(){
    el.value = exec(el.value);
    },1);
  }

 }

 $(function(){
  $('input#valorsaquemobi').bind('keypress',mask.money)
 });
  });
```

input:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control input-cadastrar rr" id="valorsaquemobi" onclick="mobisaque()">
```

Comment: Troque o onclick por onfocus.

Comment: deu certo, porem so se tiver mais um input, se n ele n deu, eu estava querendo tipo o onkeypress